# Background color on primeng p-selectButton

Tags: css, angular, primeng

How can i change background color of a primeng p-selectButton component depending on item content?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ng-template to bind dynamic classes based on the content of the button.

in component.html

```
<p-selectButton [options]="cities1" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity1">
 <ng-template let-item>
   <button class="ui-button mybtn" [ngClass]="getClass(item)">{{item.label}} 
   </button>
 </ng-template>
</p-selectButton>
```

in component.ts

```
getClass(item){
 let value = item.value;
 if(value){
    if(value.code === 'NY'){
       return 'red';
     }
     if(value.code === 'RM'){
       return 'pink';
     }
     if(value.code === 'LDN'){
       return 'green';
     }
  }
```

}

in component.scss

```
button.red, button.red:hover{
  background: red;
  border: red;
  }
  button.green, button.green:hover{
     background: green;
     border: green;
  }
  button.pink,button.pink:hover{
     background: pink;
     border: pink;
  }
 .mybtn{
    padding: 5px;
  }
```

Here is updated

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-dropdowns-bug-zcdae1)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is a way for each item already have its color before it gets selected?

Comment: Yeah, you can do that updated answer. check this kink 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-dropdowns-bug-zcdae1

Comment: @AbhinavKumar How could I change the color according to the option selected by the user. For example,  all buttons start whith the same color, but if user select New York, button selected turns green and if user selects London button selected turns red?

Comment: @Andre just posted an answer exactly for this purpose. See below.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue and found a solution directly in PrimeNG without templates and additional helper functions.

## styleClass attribute in object

The following approach is imho better as the suggested solution, as it uses the build-in functionality of PrimeNG for exactly this purpose. Just adding an attribute `styleClass` to the options objects is the way to go.

Here a property in the Controller, providing all the option-objects for the selectButton (the 'styleClass' attribute is the important part):

```
  pizzaOptions: any[] = [
    { label: "option 1: Pizza Salami", value: 1, styleClass: "p-button-danger" },
    { label: "option 2: Pizza Diavola", value: 2, styleClass: "p-button-warning" },
    { label: "option 3: Pizza Magharita", value: 3, styleClass: "p-button-success" }
  ];
```

It is suggested to use the standard style classes provided by the theme used, i.e. the p-selectButton consists of buttons, thus using existing  button classes (see [1](https://primeng.org/button#severity)) is a good way to ensure consistency with the theme.

The styleClass attribute is automatically added to the class attribute of the specific select item used to display the option. Therefore, use the p-selectButton normally, no additions needed:

```
<p-selectButton [options]="pizzaOptions" optionLabel="label" optionValue="value">
</p-selectButton>
```

Result as follows:

[image: 3 options in 3 different colors via standard button classes]

### Custom Styles

In some cases, it might be required to extend the PrimeNG standard classes. E.g. in the following example, the button highlight is overwritten in order to show an selected item in a different color, whenever the item (i.e. option) is selected.
For this, a custom class for each option has to be added, as follows:

```
pizzaOptions: any[] = [
  { label: "option 1: Info", value: 1, styleClass: "optionPizzaDiavola" },
  { label: "option 2: Warning", value: 2, styleClass: "optionPizzaSalami" }
];
```

The classes set the colors, and this is done via scss in the views scss file. Here the `:host::ng-deep` is used to show the approach.

```
:host::ng-deep {
  /* sets the style for pizza diavola */
  .p-button.p-highlight.optionPizzaDiavola {
    background: #ff0000;
    border: #cc8925;
  }

  /* sets the style for pizza Salami */
  .p-button.p-highlight.optionPizzaSalami {
    background: #0000ff;
    border: #cc8925;
  }

  /* sets the style for the hover (general) */
  .p-button.p-highlight:hover {
    background: yellow;
  }
}
```

Now looking at the generated source code while running the app, you will see, that the provided styleClasses (`optionPizzaDiavola`,`optionPizzaSalami`) have been added to the corresponding item. When selected the colors match the ones defined in the scss.

[image: rendered element]

### References / Comments

Sadly, this information never made it into the PrimeNG documentation. I discovered it scrolling through the sourcecode of the p-selectButton (see [4](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/selectbutton/selectbutton.ts)).

Similar Example with `styleClass` and `p-toggleButton` has been discussed in ([5](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/4014)).